# Evaluating a Triple Integral by switching the orders of integration

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus

I'm trying to evaluate the triple-iterated integral:

$$\int_0^4 \int_{-3\sqrt{4-x}}^{3\sqrt{4-x}} \int_{-\sqrt{x+\frac19 z^2}}^0 dy\ dz\ dx$$ 
I've tried evaluating the integral as is, but eventually got to the antiderivative:
$$\int \sqrt{x+\frac19z^2}\ dz$$
which cannot be evaluated through any normal means. I want to try to change the order of integration for the triple integral to dz dy dx, but I have no idea how to do so with the bounds given, as sketching the solid would be very difficult. How would I go about completing this problem?

Comment: Yes you can solve the integral with the substitution $z = 3 \sqrt x \sinh t$

Comment: We haven't learned how to do this, instead of performing your substitution, is it somehow possible to evaluate the triple integral by switching the order of integration?